# How to handle anger of an older colleague?

Tags: professionalism, management, colleagues

For the last 5 months I worked on a project in a team where me and other 3 developers had to build a mobile application starting from scratch.

I am the the youngest developer in this team, being between 10 to 15 years younger than other members.

During development I had the possibility to grow and "shine" enough to let my manager (who is part of the team) decide that in one month, when the application will be delivered to store and to client, I'll become the PM of this project and directly responsible of managing the team during bug fixing and evolution of the app, due to my current manager's resignation.

Despite me being very happy for that (I have 25 years and just 2 years of experience in this +400 developers company, making me very proud of my work) I recently heard from other 2 colleagues at the coffee machine, while I was at the near bathroom, that one of them is openly angry at me and he does not want to take a single order or incipit from my person.

That person used to be one of my "friends" during work (we went every day out for lunch and we used to talk about our private lives during coffee, not a close friend but something similar) and I know that the problem here is just because of my age compared to his, we both know that my skill is better .

How can I handle this situation? Note that I never had this position before, and I don't want to argue with him, not in public anyway.

Comment: This sounds a bit preliminary - you aren't even PM yet. I would not worry too much yet. See what happens first, before you start dealing with the situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leave it alone. Continue to be the PM as you normally would and if this individual does not do what he is told, then you will have to deal with it.

Lots of people will talk a big game, but when push comes to shove, they will just do the work. I have to disagree with some of the information you provided

> we both know that my skill is better

I would say this person does not think you are better suited for the job and that is probably why they are upset. Even if they don't think they are a good fit for PM, they probably believe someone else was better suited for the job.

If the person is blatantly going against what they are told, they you will have to pull that person aside and have a conversation. In this conversation you will only want to talk about the facts. So leave out any personal feelings you have and say something like:

> Bob, listen the reason I called you over is because I am concerned about your performance. On multiple occasions, your work has not been completed. Is there anything I can do to help with that?

Hopefully this will get Bob to either shape up, or at least open the pave the way for a real discussion about the actual problem. If that doesn't help, then have a conversation with the manager.

Answer (score 1):

> ... I'll become the PM of this project and directly responsible of managing the team during bug fixing and evolution of the app, due to my current manager's resignation.

Congrats, be ready.

> Despite me being very happy for that (I have 25 years and just 2 years of experience in this +400 developers company, making me very proud of my work) I recently heard from other 2 colleagues at the coffee machine, while I was at the near bathroom, that one of them is openly angry at me and he does not want to take a single order or incipit from my person.

Guess what one of your first responsibilities is going to be.

> That person used to be one of my "friends" during work (we went every day out for lunch and we used to talk about our private lives during coffee, not a close friend but something similar) and I know that the problem here is just because of my age compared to his, we both know that my skill is better.

Obviously he thought he was in the dominant role, and that you knew to listen; along with the person having trouble finding *other* people who like that, he figured you did - that's the basis of your 'friendship'.

> How can I handle this situation? Note that I never had this position before, and I don't want to argue with him, not in public anyway.

If they are useful then transfer them to a different department where they can work. Having established, in his mind, that he is the big wheel and that you roll in the manner that he decides you will never take the wheel - above you say exactly that, that people are plotting loudly at the coffee machine.

This person seems to have a few shortcomings, they need to be valuable to the company for them to remain employed there. I don't see them rethinking their decision and being able to work under you.

Discuss this with your current manager before they leave, maybe even find out why they are going. Get replacements lined up, find another division that wants to swap a couple of people (or have HR advertise for their positions).